# Where to ask question about an algorithm for sorting photos by comparing them?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange site that fits the following question? I was thinking maybe Mathematics?

> I have digitized about 1000 old photos. Currently they are not sorted. I would like to order them chronologically. I'm thinking of showing 2 at a time with the question which is the oldest. The answers would be "left, right or unknown"
>
> Is there a mathematical explanation/solution for this?
> I'm not even sure what I'm looking for, is it an algorithm?
> Is there an algorithm for doing this which reduces the amount of comparisons?

Comment: Welcome to Meta SE. FYI, what you are describing, if the 2 pictures you're showing are consecutive, is similar to the [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) algorithm.

Comment: Your question is so overly broad that I don't think any site in particular would be a good fit.

Comment: "I'm not even sure what I'm looking for" No site.

Answer (score 7):

The difficulty of your problem is that it might require the expertise of *several* Stack Exchange sites, depending on your current experience.

To help with *designing* the solution, [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) might be your best bet (but I have a hunch the question has already been asked there, or else is quickly answerable with an adequate Google search.)

To help with *implementing* it, that will depend on several factors:

- what operating system are you using?
- how is the metadata of the photos accessible?
- is there an off-the-shelf program to do what you want?
- do you want to program it, and if so, what languages/frameworks/platforms/operation systems are you familiar with?